# Checkbox with Specify textfield below the checkbox

Tags: iphone, checkbox

I have ten check box in the application. if the user press the checkbox then in the next line there will be UITextfield added.

can any one have suggestion on how to do it more faster because its have lots of condition for checking ?
Please check with the screen shot i have mentioned.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would implement this using a UITableView with 2 custom cells

1. one for your checkbox and text
2. one for your textfield

And then for instance on `– tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` for the checkbox cells you implement `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` to insert your textField cell below the selected checkbox cell

Hope this helps and gets you on the right track

Comment: if you have any source code sample then please share me if possible! Thanks

Comment: Have a look at this WWDC 2011 session (you have to be a registered iOS developer to watch it): https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/includes/uitableview-changes-tips-tricks.html#uitableview-changes-tips-tricks